# How to set attributes with accessors into a model properly in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
class Theme
{
    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return 'prefix-' . $this->id;
    }
}


$theme = Theme::find(1);

dump($theme->name); // "prefix-1"

$array = $theme->toArray();

dump($array) // ["id" => 1]
```

The "name" attribute does not appear in the array, so I have to add the following code (or add `$theme->name = ''` before `toArray()`):

```
$array['name'] = $theme->name;

dump($array) // ["id" => 1, "name" => "prefix-1"]

return $array;
```

Is there any other way to do this more elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the property to the `$appends` variable on you model.

```
class Theme
{
    protected $appends = ['name'];

    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return 'prefix-' . $this->id;
    }
}
```

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks